# DNS Lookup: Get IP Address From DNS/Host Name

Tags: php, dns, gethostbyname

I need to get the IP address of a domain by the domain name.

1. Site: hotmail.com / 65.55.72.151
2. Site: domain.com / 65.254.244.180

Can it be done, and in that case, how can I do it?

Comment: Use [`gethostbyname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) :)

Comment: Who eat up the code from between the tags ? :p

Comment: i want it using php ? - Rocket Hazmat

Comment: Rikesh - by mistake :P

Comment: Hadidi44: use the @-form to call someone, e.g. @Rikesh. You can edit your own question and put the code back in.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel : lol u didn't do it :P

Comment: It's not necessary when calling the OP of a posting, but to call someone else in a comment thread, you need the @-form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
<?php
$ip = gethostbyname('www.site.com');

echo $ip;
?>
```

Or, you could operate it dynamically...

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
$ip = gethostbyname($url);

echo $ip;
?>
```